# Android Database Instance Class

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need a suggestions how to achieve something in android and Java. I have a big project which has more than 50 activities and I use two different database classes to query sqlite statements and retrieve information from my system and user database. Here is an example how I am using and initializing my database :

```
SystemDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new SystemDatabaseHelper(this, null, 1);
dbHelper.initialize(this);
```

I am doing that in activity and the last few days I read a lot for memory leaks in android and the whole information about giving `Context` to a non-activity classes and the leaks which this can cause. My question is which is the best way to create some class and initialize it only from main activity and than use it in all other activities without initializing it again and again.

Any suggestions which is the best way to achieve this...i have some ideas,but want to hear your suggestions and best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to initialize your database helper class only once you're looking for singleton right?? here is an example how you can make it

```
public class ContactDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private ContactDBHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    private static ContactDBHelper mInstance;

    public static synchronized ContactDBHelper getInstance() {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new ContactDBHelper(Util.getApplicationContext(),
                    ContactDB.DB_NAME, null, ContactDB.DB_VERSION);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(ContactDB.Contact.CREATE_STMT);
        db.execSQL(ContactDB.Contact.CREATE_PHONE_NUMBER_INDEX);
        db.execSQL(ContactDB.Contact.CREATE_REVERSE_PHONE_NUMBER_INDEX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

if you call `ContactDBHelper.getInstance();` the first time , it will initialize the instance , after that any application component or any method will call it , it wont initialize it will return the singleton initialized instance .
 note : for the Util.getApplicationContext it is a static  helper method that returns application context which is set in the main Activity .

for memory leaks , you can avoid or protect your app from it using `WeakReference` or `SoftRerference`

here is the Util class

```
public class Util {

    private static WeakReference<Context> applicationContext;

    public static Context getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext.get();
    }

    public static void setApplicationContext(Context context) {
        applicationContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was thinking to do something like that, but didn't thought using WeakReference. It was really helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the application class and use a single global reference.  This also has the advantage of not using an Activity context.

```
public class NameOfApp extends Application {  

    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

          super.onCreate();

          try{

               // this will create the database if required (e.g. new install or db deleted)
               db=new Database(this.getBaseContext()).getWritableDatabase();        

          } catch (Exception e) {

               // TODO add alert and quit
               Log.e(TAG,"Error creating DB:" + e.getMessage());
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating DB:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    } // onCreate

    @Override
    public void onTerminate(){
         Log.d(TAG, "Application.onTerminate() database closed");
         super.onTerminate();
         savePreferences();
         db.close();
    }

    public void closeDB(){
          db.close();
          Log.d(TAG,"Database closed on request");
    }

    protected SQLiteDatabase getwritableDatabase(){
        return db;
    }

}
```

Use MyAppName.getWritableDatabase().

Comment: <b>You Should not</b> relay on <i>onTerminate()</i> its not guaranteed to be called , actually you can relay on android System which gonna close all system resources when it kill the process of the application . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()

Comment: I don't rely on onTerminate().  That's why closeDB() is there :)